# Custom field reference problem in profileSearchLayouts metadata

Tags: deployment, custom-field, metadata, search-layout

In a sandbox I've created a custom object with some fields.  In Lightning, I've created some Search Layouts for different community profiles.  I've noticed that the metadata looks like this:

```
<profileSearchLayouts>
    <fields>NAME</fields>
    <fields>RECORDTYPE</fields>
    <fields>00N1k000002quqz</fields>
    <fields>CREATED_DATE</fields>
    <profileName>MyCustom Community User</profileName>
</profileSearchLayouts>
```

Where `00N1k000002quqz` is actually a custom field in the object.

When I try to deploy the whole object to production, I'm getting an error

> ProfileSearchLayoutsFields 00N1k000002quqz not found

I think this because when the fields are created in production, they have different IDs.

Does anyone know why IDs are used instead of the API names?  I used Developer Workbench at API v. 48 to retrieve the sandbox metadata for deployment.

Comment: Hello, had same issue, reverted back to v.47 in package.xml and it seems ok now

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have some other metadata items that require v48.

Comment: Yeah, you should open a case or an issue, and have SF look at it :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the Id to the API name of the field.